# Migrate email account from cPanel to a non control panel server

Tags: email, cpanel, ubuntu, dedicated-hosting

How to migrate my email account without losing any data, in cPanel you have a `/etc` folder with all the config file, but how I can migrate that from my cPanel to my dedicated server in my case with Ubuntu 12.04LTS with no control panel?

Answer (score 1):

The article '[How to Export All Emails From cPanel](http://www.ehow.com/how_8507632_export-emails-cpanel.html)' at ehow might be of help to you.